# What pairs well with the "time travel" game type?

Tags: game-dev-story

What pairs well with "time travel" in *Game Dev Story*?

Comment: I really wish I had an iWhatever 'cause all these game-dev-story questions paint an interesting picture.

Comment: It's just a business sim with a game hardware/software development theme.

Comment: What is the question?  I don't understand it.

Comment: I've not found a combination that works yet! Perhaps its a bug? I've mostly used the gamefaq faq which I thought was a comprehensive list but even that doesn't mention a combination.

Comment: @BeemerGuy: The question makes perfect sense if you've played Game Dev Story.

Comment: The combination result are not always the same. Sometime Amazing combination may not happen as you staff don't do it well. BTW, have you ever play Chrono Trigger? :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with Adventure. Went pretty well. It depends though. Even if you have a somewhat strange combination, if the direction is right as per the genre and the parameters (Fun, Creativity, Graphics and Sound) have high enough points, there are high chances that the combination will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it couple of times but not sure right now.

Though i generally give audio-novels a go on weird genres. So time-travel/audio-novel works pretty well as i remember. ( like publishing H.G.Wells Time Machine :)

Other than that action and adventure should work too.

If you need some cheats; 
http://app.downloadatoz.com/tutorial,8289,game-dev-story-compelet-unlock-guide-and-hints.html
looks good, giving some idea about the game mechanics, i never knew i can open so many differen genres till now :)